# Move sprite in pygame without flickering

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been playing around in pygame, and I can draw and use the `update` method to move my sprite, but when I clear the screen the sprite flickers. How do I move the sprite without the flickering

Here's the code:

```py
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = demon
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        self.rect.x += moveX
        self.rect.y += moveY
        screen.fill(BLACK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical Pygame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Remove `screen.fill(BLACK)` form `update`:

```py
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]
    
    def update(self, moveX, moveY):
        self.rect.x += moveX
        self.rect.y += moveY
        # screen.fill(BLACK)         <--- DELETE
```

Implement the following application loop (based on your previous question):

```py
while carryOn == True:

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False

    # update
    # [...]

    # clear display
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: whoops, clicked the wrong arrow... :-)

Comment: Clicked to fast. Good answer as always!